# Flot Graph is not showing when using time in xaxis

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm trying to use flot to graph data and have the time for data along the x axis. The graph works fine until I add time mode in the options. Everything I've seen says the problem is the time stamp but I've converted it to the Javascript time stamp. Here is the code I have.

```
    var data = [[1272701100000,2.475],[1272701400000,2.475],[1272701700000,2.475],[1272702000000,2.7],[1272702300000,2.745],[1272702600000,2.7],[1272702900000,2.565],[1272703200000,2.475],[1272703500000,2.385],[1272703800000,2.52]];
    var options = {xaxis: {
        mode: "time"
    }};
    $.plot("#placeholder",[data]);
```

Comment: So what happens when you run this code? Can you provide a full example?

Comment: are you passing your `options` object into the `$.plot()` method? You aren't in your example.

Comment: Here it is an example without the options http://jsfiddle.net/nULPV/1048/ and one with the options http://jsfiddle.net/nULPV/1047/. I copied over the code without the options being passed in on accident.

Comment: @Joe You aren't including the [`jquery.flot.time.js`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) plugin in either of your JSFiddles. The time plugin is required to for time series support.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine when you include the Flot time plugin: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nULPV/1049/)

[image]

Error was in the console:

```
Error: Time mode requires the flot.time plugin.
```